# Is the only difference between tDMRG and TEBD the way the central sites are shifted?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, spin-chains, algorithms, tensor-network

I have been reading up on time evolution methods using matrix product states. Reading from Schollwoeck's notes on the density matrix renormalization group, (https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3477), I looked at the tDMRG and TEBD methods, and the comparison thereof (section 7.3.3). It is noted that tDMRG advances the two active sites forward with two SVDs so that one can apply a Trotter decomposed time evolution operator. TEBD instead stores the singular values across each bond and uses relationships between the left and right canonical forms to shift the active sites.

From an implementation perspective, are there any other important differences between the two methods?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.